# Nginx перенаправление по условиям

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно перенаправить в NGINX все обращения к url http://example.com/some/page.php на http://example.com/, если они пришли с внешних ресурсов. И при этом сохранить возможность перехода по ссылкам, если они были инициированы с сайта http://example.com/.

То есть в выдаче гугла мы видим ссылку на ресурс: http://example.com/page/with/some/content.html, но нажимая на нее должны попасть на http://example.com/
А при переходе с главной страницы сайта на все дочерние получаем результат без редиректов: http://example.com/index.php -> http://example.com/page/with/some/content.html.

Comment: интересно что потом будет в том самом гугле при переиндексации страниц...

Comment: Это не важно на текущем этапе.

Answer (score 1):

```
location / {
    if ($http_referer !~* (www.)?site.ru) {
        return 301 /;
    }
    ...
}
```